# How to generate double length 3-DES key in Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, des

I am looking for information, code examples, java library on how to generate the **double length 3-DES key**s. Can somebody direct me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: By "double length", do you mean a 112-bit (16-byte) key, with only 80 bits of effective strength?

Comment: @erickson thank you for your message. I am not actually sure. I need to generate a double length 3-DES key and this is my first time looking into it. So, I am trying to find us much as possible about it and so far, decided to better understand the Java Cryptography Specification here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html. If you know how to Generate at least single length 3DES key, I will be thankful if you share how to.

Comment: How do you know you need to generate a "double length" 3des key?

Comment: I dont' get the close votes. Don't equate your knowledge with that of others (it's a mistake I made myself in the past as well). And describe what you are expecting from the asker when you do vote to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will generate 112-bit key for DES-EDE. While a 112-bit key is requested, the SunJCE provider will return a 24-byte key. This is because one bit in each byte is a parity bit (adding 16 bits to the 112 to make 128 bits or 16 bytes), then the first 8 bytes are repeated, for a total of 24 bytes.

```
KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
gen.init(112);
SecretKey key = gen.generateKey();
```

Note that this key only has 80 bits of effective strength, and cannot be considered strong encryption. Don't use this for anything important.

Comment: @erickson, please allow me ask you one more question. I am learning that this is not the correct way to generate the double length 3DES key. A way to do it is to generate an instance of KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede"). Then take the first 8 bytes and concatenate it with the second 8 bytes and then add the first 8 bytes again and now when we have this new array of 24 bytes generate a new DESede key out of it.. Does it look like a correct way to create a double length 3DES key to you?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes do you think the way I have describe above is a correct way to create double length 3DES key?

Comment: Absolutely. Using a key factory this was is definitely the preferred way. It should e.g. also be compatible with hardware crypto providers. And - if supported - it should be used instead of the three key hack, which isn't.

Comment: @Simplyi Sorry, I didn't understand your question, but yes, I concur with Maarten for the reasons he cites. This is the correct way to generate such a key, and I would be suspicious of a provider that didn't support this usage.